# Saving mutiple rows or WHILE array into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I am trying to multiple data into database. I have while array from a table echo the value into form so i want to save this array to another table.

Here is sample code:

**Main.php**

```
<form method="post" action="save.php">
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM fix limit 4";
    $query=mysql_query($sql1);
    if($query){
        echo '<div class="home">
        <input type="text" name="home[]">
        </div>
        <div class="away">
            <input type="text" name="away[]">
        </div>';
</form>
```

**save.php**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'== 'POST']{
    $home=$_POST['home'];
    $away=$_POST['away'];
    $ps="INSERT INTO predictions (home, away) VALUES('$home', '$away')";
    $pq= mysql_query($ps) or die(mysql_error());
    if($pq){
        header('location: myprediction.php');   
    }
}
```

So i tried array like this

```
foreach($home as $key1=>$TheHome){
    $first= $TheHome;
}  
foreach($away as $key2=>$TheAway){
    $second= $Theaway;
}
```

This is also not saving multiple rows.

**PLEASE HELP, THANKS**

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'== 'POST']` change to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')`

Comment: what do you mean by not working ? can you post what error you are getting ?

Comment: Not submitting multiple data. Only last row was submitted

Comment: mysql_* deprecated and may be removed in the next version, please use mysqli_* or PDO